# Submit Form with jQuery or Javascript or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, submit

Is it possible to submit a form with a script?

I know it must be because these days there are tons of forms that ask you to fill in numbers. But what script can do this anyway? How is it done using PHP, Javascript or jQuery... ajax?

For example. I am uploading images and info about products on a website. I am wondering if I have to mannually go to the website or if I can submit different info from my database. Make sense?

Comment: Why the minus one? If your going to put a minus one just explain what I did wrong.

Comment: i gave a +1 , b/c of that guy the first day of posting!  So, you seem to have 2 downvoters.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery.ajax() to send a request to a server side function.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Using AJAX (jQuery has a bunch of useful and easy-to-implement AJAX methods) you can pass data to your server. There are a bunch of security issues regarding cross-domain AJAX though, and if I understand you correctly, this is what you're trying to achieve.

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/